# Reusing Group of Fields in GraphQL Schema

Tags: javascript, graphql

I've got a certain set of GraphQL fields that I would like to re-use across a bunch of different types.

The current type looks like this, and it pertains to my Pagination information:

```
  type Pagination {
    totalDocs: Int!
    limit: Int!
    totalPages: Int!
    page: Int!
    offset: Int!
    pagingCounter: Int!
    hasPrevPage: Boolean!
    hasNextPage: Boolean!
    prevPage: Int
    nextPage: Int
  }
```

There are several types which should include this information. I'm aware that I could nest the information in a sub-field, and then have that subfield point to this type. Like this:

```
type House {
    cost: Int!
    size: Int!
    pagination: Pagination
}
```

However, I'd rather not nest the information if that's possible. For example, the completed types might look

```
type House {
    cost: Int!
    size: Int!
    totalDocs: Int!
    limit: Int!
    totalPages: Int!
    page: Int!
    offset: Int!
    pagingCounter: Int!
    hasPrevPage: Boolean!
    hasNextPage: Boolean!
    prevPage: Int
    nextPage: Int
  }


type Car {
    speed: Int!
    color: String!
    totalDocs: Int!
    limit: Int!
    totalPages: Int!
    page: Int!
    offset: Int!
    pagingCounter: Int!
    hasPrevPage: Boolean!
    hasNextPage: Boolean!
    prevPage: Int
    nextPage: Int
  }
```

Is it possible to extract the repetitive fields into another common chunk and share it across multiple types, without nesting the data inside of another field. With objects, for example, something similar would be possible with the spread (`...`) operator.

Something like this?

```
type Car {
        cost: Int!
        size: Int!
        ...pagination
      }
```

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces

Comment: You can create an interface with all the fields in it. Then when you create new type you need to implement the interface with all the fields, you will still need to write all the fields but it will give you error when one field is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're forming them with gql tag or some other string-based system, you can abstract them out into a common type and Template-literal them in.

```js
const Pagination = `
    totalDocs: Int!
    limit: Int!
    totalPages: Int!
    page: Int!
    offset: Int!
    pagingCounter: Int!
    hasPrevPage: Boolean!
    hasNextPage: Boolean!
    prevPage: Int
    nextPage: Int
`;

module.exports = `
  type Car {
    cost: Int!
    size: Int!
    ${Pagination}
  }

  type House {
    cost: Int!
    size: Int!
    ${Pagination}
  }
`;
```